# JavaFX8 Style not immediately updating

Tags: css, javafx, java-8

I am trying to change the color of the table rows when I set a boolean.

So I have this code:

```
boolean searchmode = false;
....

columns.forEach(c -> c.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<ShowableInWarenkorb, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? null : item);
                if (searchmode) {
                    getStyleClass().add("searchmode");
                } else{
                    getStyleClass().remove("searchmode");
                }
            }
        };
    }));
```

This CSS:

```
.searchmode {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.3);
})
```

And then I switch searchmode eventually in my code before I am updating the table contents.

But the color does not change immediatley, sometimes I have to click a little bit around before it changes, how can I trigger it manually?

Comment: What is `searchmode`?

Comment: added it to the code... it indicates if I want the color from the searchmode class or not

Comment: It looks like you are changing the text of all the columns in the table to gray if searchmode is true, is that correct?

Comment: not the text, the background of the cols becomes gray with an opacity of 0.2. The changed color of the table should indicate the mode

Comment: Yes, sorry, background color. But all cells at once, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you want to apply this to all cells in the table. You can do this without a cell factory at all (though you may need one for other purposes).

Do

```
PseudoClass searchmodePseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("searchmode");
```

and then when you change the value of searchmode, do

```
table.pseudoClassStateChanged(searchmode);
```

In your css, do

```
.table-view:searchmode .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.3);
}
```

If you want to "automate" the update to the pseudoclass state, use a boolean property and add a listener:

```
private final BooleanProperty searchmode = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

public final boolean isSearchmode() { 
    return searchmodeProperty().get();
}
public final void setSearchmode(boolean searchmode) {
    searchmodeProperty().set(searchmode);
}
public BooleanProperty searchmodeProperty() {
    return searchmode ;
}
```

Then if you add the listener

```
searchmode.addListener((obs, wasSearchmode, isNowSearchmode) -> 
    table.pseudoClassStateChanged(searchmodePseudoClass, isNowSearchmode));
```

everything will be wired automatically so the table changes whenever you call `setSearchmode(...)`.

Comment: wow, this is amazing, thankyou. Solved my problem perfectly. What is a pseudoclass? Is it what the colon in the css indicates?

Comment: Yes, a CSS pseudoclass. There are some standard ones (hover, etc), but in JavaFX 8 you can just define your own. Here's a [CSS only description](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). And the [Javadocs for the JavaFX implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html)